# Trying to assign 2-D array of size 6

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
for i in xrange(6):
    arr[i]=map(int,raw_input().strip().split())
```

it is showing

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: Put a minimal reproducible example. There are unknown variables (such as `arr`). We have to be able to reproduce the code, in order to figure out what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to do it:

```
arr = [map(int, raw_input("enter values for row %d: " % i).strip().split())
        for i in xrange(6)]
print arr
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems :

First, you do not initialize the list before using it. Thus, `arr` is used as a list, even though it may have been created as another type of variable.

Second, you want to change the value for index `i` when there is no value for this index.

You can either create a list of six elements beforehand : `arr = [ 0,0,0,0,0,0]` or you can add the elements to the list as you create them : `for i in xrange(6): arr.append(map(int,raw_input().strip().split()))`

I do not know if it possible to create a list of a given size without giving values in python, though =/

Comment: Folks often use `None` to mean "no value", so you could use `arr = [None for _ in xrange(N)]` to pre-allocate a list of `N` elements without values.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
final=[]
for i in range(6):
    final.append(list(map(int,input().split())))
```

Now you have all your inputs in a list final